# Search from one view through a joined HABTM table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up a simple search from one view through a joined table and, being a newbie, it's not quite working. I'm testing with the word "books" which I know is in the articles table in the subject column.

My error is:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: articles.subject: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "keywords"  WHERE (articles.subject LIKE '%books%')

My schema is:

```
 create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"

  end

  create_table "articles_keywords", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "article_id"
    t.integer "keyword_id"
  end

  create_table "keywords", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "keyword"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

My model is:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles


  def self.search_for(query)
    where('articles.subject LIKE :query', :query => "%#{query}%")
  end
```

My controller action is:

```
  def index
    @keywords = params[:q] ? Keyword.search_for(params[:q]) : Keyword.all
  end
```

My view action is:

```
<%= form_tag "/", method: "GET" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>


<% if @keywords.any? %>

  <% @keywords.each do |k| %>
    <section>
      <h3><b>Title</b>: <%= link_to k.keyword.title, keyword.title %></h3>
      <p><b>Subject</b>: <%= keyword.subject%></p>

  <% end %>
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to `join` the asocciated table (and you can use scopes):

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles

    scope :search_for, ->(query){ joins(:acticles).where('articles.subject LIKE :query', :query => "%#{query}%")}

end
```

See [RubyOnRails-Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

A gem that eases complex querying is [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel). With squeel the scope would by

```
scope :search_for, ->(query){ joins{articles}.where{articles.subject =~ "%#{query}%"} }
```

Comment: Thanks! You have an extra close parenthesis in the scope statement, but once I removed that my error went away. However, while everything appears it is not performing the search and I know the word appears in the column as I was able to successfully find it in the console. So I think I need to make another adjustement somewhere.

Comment: A goot tool to develop queries it the `to_sql` method. In a rails console type `Keyword.search_for('foo').to_sql` and analyze the sql statement.